# Entity Framework Core does not include related entities while filtering

Tags: .net, ef-core-2.0

I have an uncommon issue with EF Core.

Here is my method:

```
public async Task<Tuple<List<ProductDto>, int>> GetFilteredAsync(MainFilter filter)
{
    var filteredQuery = _repository.GetAll();

    if (filter.Active)
        filteredQuery = filteredQuery.Where(p => p.Active);

    filteredQuery = filteredQuery.Where(p => p.ProductAvailableDates.Any(pad => pad.Date.CompareDateWihtoutTime(filter.AvailableFrom) >= 0));

    if (filter.AvailableTo.HasValue)
    {
        filteredQuery = filteredQuery.Where(p => p.ProductAvailableDates.Any(pad => pad.Date.CompareDateWihtoutTime(filter.AvailableTo.Value) <= 0));
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.City))
    {
        filteredQuery = filteredQuery.Where(p => p.City.Equals(filter.City));
    }

    if (filter.CategoryId.HasValue)
    {
        filteredQuery = filteredQuery.Where(p => p.CategoryProducts.Any(cp => cp.CategoryId == filter.CategoryId.Value));
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.NameSubset))
        filteredQuery = filteredQuery.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(filter.NameSubset));

    if (filter.PriceHigherThan.HasValue)
        filteredQuery = filteredQuery.Where(p => p.Price > filter.PriceHigherThan);

    if (filter.PriceLowerThan.HasValue)
        filteredQuery = filteredQuery.Where(p => p.Price < filter.PriceLowerThan);

    if (filter.UserId.HasValue)
        filteredQuery = filteredQuery.Where(p => p.OwnerId.Equals(filter.UserId));

    filteredQuery = filteredQuery.Include(x => x.ProductImages);

    var numberOfEntities = filteredQuery.Count();

    // order items
    switch (filter.OrderItem)
    {
        case "name":
            filteredQuery = filteredQuery.OrderByAscOrDesc(filter.Ascending, x => x.Name);
            break;

        case "price":
            filteredQuery = filteredQuery.OrderByAscOrDesc(filter.Ascending, x => x.Price);
            break;

        case "creation_time":
            filteredQuery = filteredQuery.OrderByAscOrDesc(filter.Ascending, x => x.CreatedAt);
            break;
    }

    filteredQuery = filteredQuery.Paginate(filter);
    var filteredList = await filteredQuery.ToListAsync();

    var dtoList = await ConvertModelListToDtoList(filteredList);

    return new Tuple<List<ProductDto>, int>(dtoList, numberOfEntities);
}
```

Which filter my products based on filters parameter (works fine) but my entity Products loses his raleted data like: imagesUrls and ProductAvailableDate. When method repository.getAll is called there are available and returned but problem accurs when my query is getting filtered and related entities with product are getting lost for 2 products (which have more than 1 imageUrl) but for 3rd and last one there is everything fine.

Product entity:

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<CategoryProduct> CategoryProducts { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeactivetedAt { get; set; }
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
    public List<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
    public List<ProductAvailableDate> ProductAvailableDates { get; set; }
```

`.Include()` doesn't help here.

Comment: Did you check the generated queries? That would narrow down the possible causes of this issue.

Comment: After: filteredQuery = filteredQuery.Where(p => p.ProductAvailableDates.Any(pad => pad.Date.CompareDateWihtoutTime(filter.AvailableFrom) >= 0));
he returns products but without related data

Comment: Sure. But you should check the *SQL* queries.